# Tooltip is not getting displayed

Tags: d3.js

I am working on this bar graph in the fiddle. I have tried to append tooltip but it only changes color on mouseover, no value is getting displayed.[Here's the fiddle i am working on](https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/2/)

I am appending tooltip as-

```
                                  d3.select('#tooltip')
                                    .style('left', xPos + 'px')
                                    .style('top', yPos + 'px')
                                    .style('display','block')
                                    .select('#value')
                                    .text(d.global);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a div with id tooltip for this to work.  I also edited the mouseover and mouseout functions.  They should act on the rectangle so I moved them upward and calculated xPos and yPos based on your equations.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c74eoo2b/6/

HTML

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

JS

```
.on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
    var xPos = xScale(i);
    var yPos = yScale((d.global / total) * 100);

    d3.select('#tooltip')
        .style('left', xPos + 'px')
        .style('top', yPos + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block')
        .html(d.global);
})
.on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.select('#tooltip').style('display', 'none');
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @link ,is there any way to place the tooltip at the top of the bars?